# Defining a struct instance in a header file

Tags: c++, struct

I'm trying to define a struct instance in a header file inside a namespace.

I have a file named `initializers.h`:

```
   #ifndef INITIALIZERS_H
   #define INITIALIZERS_H
   
   namespace initializers
   {
       // Struct to define spaceships
       struct spaceship
       {
           int nx;
           int ny;
           int** ship;
       };
  
       // Declare spaceships
       extern spaceship ss_30P5H2V0;
   }

  #endif
```

What I want to do is to define the `extern` variable in a different file in order to use it in my main.cpp script. I do that in the `initializers.cpp` file:

```
   #include "initializers.h"
   
   namespace initializers
   {
       // Define spaceships
       spaceship ss_30P5H2V0;
       ss_30P5H2V0.nx   = 11;
       ss_30P5H2V0.ny   = 13;
       // ss_30P5H2V0->ship = zeros(ss_30P5H2V0.nx,ss_30P5H2V0.ny);
       // ss_30P5H2V0.ship = {
       //                     {0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
       //                     {0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
       //                     {0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0},
       //                     {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
       //                     {0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0},
       //                     {1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0},
       //                     {1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
       //                     {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1},
       //                     {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0},
       //                     {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1},
       //                     {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
       //                 };   
   }
```

My main file tries to use the variable `ss_30P5H2V0` but when I compile (`g++ simulate.cpp conway.cpp initializers.cpp`) I get the following error:

> ```
> initializers.cpp:7:5: error: ‘ss_30P5H2V0’ does not name a type
>     7 |     ss_30P5H2V0.nx   = 11;
>       |     ^~~~~~~~~~~
> initializers.cpp:8:5: error: ‘ss_30P5H2V0’ does not name a type
>     8 |     ss_30P5H2V0.ny   = 13;
>       |     ^~~~~~~~~~~
> ```

I don't quite understand why this error is happening.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A namespace scope, like a file scope, can only contain declarations and definitions. You put two assignments there. You need to set up your values in the initialization.

Comment: Also, you can't convert a two-dimensional array of `int` into an `int**`.

Comment: I would recommend that you use more modern structures, such as `std::array` or `std::vector`.

Comment: How is `int** ship;` related to an array of bools?? And you should not name a header or source file as "script" in a compiled language.

Comment: A more minimal example of your specific problem is the program `int x; x = 1; int main() {}`. That is, it has nothing to do with headers, namespaces, structs, or `extern`, but is very fundamental.

Comment: My point is more that I want to define a series of pre-defined struct variables to be used externally...

Comment: Vincius, @molbdnilo has diagnosed your problem perfectly. Try to understand their comment. In particular, your problem would remain even if you included your definition of `struct spaceship` directly in the `c` file.

Comment: Yes, I got the point now! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have expression statements in namespace scope. If you wish to modify the variable, then you must do so within a function.

You may also initialise the variable with desired values, instead of modifying it after initialisation.